# How do I copy/backup my dotenv files and config files from one computer to another in Git

Tags: git

It's generally not great practice to store secrets (.env files) in git. However when I need to move computers, I usually have to copy and paste them individually one by one.

I don't want to copy the entire git repository because it also contains `node_modules` and would take forever through Google. How can I copy just my env files?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your sites dir

```sh
setopt sh_word_split # For zsh

dirs=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -prune -print 2>/dev/null)

# store dotfiles here
[[ ! -d dotfiles ]] && mkdir dotfiles
dotfiles_path=$(cd dotfiles && pwd)

for dir in $dirs; do
    originalPwd=$(pwd)
    cd $dir
    ignored=$(git status --ignored)
    for file in $ignored; do
        if [[ -f $file ]]; then
            new_location="$dotfiles_path/$dir/$(dirname $file)"
            mkdir -p $new_location
            cp $file $new_location
        fi
    done
    cd $originalPwd
done
```

Copy the files to Google Drive:

```sh
cp -r dotfiles ~/Google\ Drive\
```

Wait for files to sync

On new computer, go to your `~/Sites` directory and do

```sh
cp -r ~/Google\ Drive/dotfiles/* .
```

And everything is synced using minimal bandwidth :)

You can also put this in a script and on a cron job to auto backup

```
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Paste:

```
*/10 * * * * ~/Sites/backupEnv.sh
```